# Does exist on Go something like macros in C++ like #ifdef so I can choose what to build based on flag?

Tags: go

I need to build in go for linux and windows with different packages same file
on windows I need to `import github.com/hashicorp/go-syslog` and on linux `import log/syslog`

and inside code in file I have to use `syslog.ALERT` or `gsyslog.ALERT` depending on os. Does exist on `Go` something like macros in `C++` like `#ifdef` so I can choose what to build based on flag ? How to achieve this without, same file to have different content for build based on OS ?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but since the whole point of that wrapper is to negate this issue, why not just use the wrapper for both platforms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what [build tags](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) are for:

> A build constraint, also known as a build tag, is a line comment that begins
>
> ```
> // +build
> ```
>
> that lists the conditions under which a file should be included in the package. Constraints may appear in any kind of source file (not just Go), but they must appear near the top of the file, preceded only by blank lines and other line comments. These rules mean that in Go files a build constraint must appear before the package clause.

Another way to distinguish OS/arch at runtime is to use runtime's [GOOS and GOARCH constants](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#pkg-constants):

> GOARCH is the running program's architecture target: 386, amd64, or arm.
>
> GOOS is the running program's operating system target: one of darwin, freebsd, linux, and so on.

Answer (score 6):

You can work with **build tags** as described [here](http://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/12/how-to-use-conditional-compilation-with-the-go-build-tool).

In a nutshell, insert a comment like

```
// +build linux
```

at the top of your file and this file will only build on linux.
Accordingly

```
// +build windows
```

will only build the file on windows.

**Be sure to put a blank line** after the afforementioned comment. Read [this](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) for reference.